# Jackson @JsonView for long chain of associations on JPA/Hibernate entity graph

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I have the following code:

```
public interface JSONInvoiceView {

    public interface JSONInvoiceBasicView {

    }

    public interface JSONInvoiceWithLinesView extends JSONInvoiceBasicView {

    }
}

@PersistenceUnit(unitName="ERP_PU")
@Entity 
@Table(name="INVOICE")
public class Invoice extends FrameworkEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PK_INVOICE_GEN", sequenceName = "PK_INVOICE_GEN", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PK_INVOICE_GEN")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceBasicView.class)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="invoiceLine", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesView.class)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<InvoiceLine> lines = new ArrayList<InvoiceLine>();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DATE")
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceBasicView.class)
    private Date startDate;

    //...
}

@PersistenceUnit(unitName="ERP_PU")
@Entity 
@Table(name="INVOICE_LINE")
public class InvoiceLine extends FrameworkEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesView.class)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_INVOICE")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Invoice invoice;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesView.class)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_GOOD")
    private Good good;

    //...
}
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="ERP_PU")
@Entity 
@Table(name="GOOD")
public class Good extends FrameworkEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length=200)
    private String description;

//...
}
```

So – one Invoice can have multiple InvoiceLines and each line has reference to Good. I need to get two JSON views: Inovice-only view and Invoice+InvoiceLine-only view. My domain is far richer than these 3 classes – the whole entity graph involves tens of classes and I need careful control how much of this graph I am loading in my entities. But I need to control also how much of loaded graph the JSON serialization facility should try to serialize. And I have the problem with this second control.

`entityList` is list of Invoices which has loaded InvoiceLines (with touch, e.g. invoiceLines.size();) but InvoiceLines have not further loaded Goods (invoiceLine.good is not touched during lazy load). So, entityList if Invoice+InvoiceLines.

I use the following code for Invoice-only view and this code works:

```
jsonString = objectMapper.writerWithView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceBasicView.class).writeValueAsString(entityList);
```

Code for retrieving JSON view with Invoice+InvoiceLine-only data:

```
jsonString = objectMapper.writerWithView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesView.class).writeValueAsString(entityList);
```

And this code does not work, it raises error message:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->mycom.entities.Invoice["invoiceLines"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-> mycom.entities.Good["good"]-> mycom.entities.Good_$$_jvst4f9_c["id"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.SerializerBase.wrapAndThrow(SerializerBase.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
```

So, the question is – **what Jackson views/annotations should I apply to serialized Invoice+InvoiceLine only parts of entity graph which has loaded only Invoice+InvoiceLine data? How should I indicate that Jackson should not try to go further along association chain and Jackson should not try to serialize 3rd, 4th and so order associations, Jackson should not try to serialize good entities?**

p.s. Ignore annotations (or any similar global annotation on entities) is not applicable in my case, because there will be cases when I need only Invoice data and then there will be cases when I will need Invoice+InvoiceLine+Good data and further I will need data Invoice+InvoiceLine+Good+GoodSupplier, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution - Jackson perceives fields without @JsonView annotation as the fields belonging to every view. Therefor I should introduce additional view:

public interface JSONInvoiceView {

```
    public interface JSONInvoiceBasicView {

    }

    public interface JSONInvoiceWithLinesView extends JSONInvoiceBasicView {

    }

    public interface JSONInvoiceWithLinesViewExt extends JSONInvoiceWithLinesView { 
    }

}
```

And apply new interace to the Good field:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="FK_GOOD")
@JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesExtView.class)
private Good good;
```

So - I should define new JSON view interfeice for each level of associations for my entities. After appling @JsonView all works like a charm.